# error class not removing after enter correct date format in text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Currently working on jquery date picker where if user enter some random numbers other the correct date format an error message will come in the top and alert will come then red border will come in text field. with my current code i am getting this perfectly but if user enter the correct date errRed class and top label  message was not hiding.

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/akwb5r3L/5/)

Here is my code

```
<span id="error_message" class="error_msge">

</span> 
<div>&nbsp;</div>
 <form autocomplete="off" class="basicForm" id="basicForm" method="POST" action="education_health.html">
  <input type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="ipt_Field txt_Idt ipt_required" id="txt_Idt" name="txt_Idt" />
 </form>
```

Here is the jquery code which i am trying

```
$('.txt_Idt').change(function (event) {
    var txtVal = $('.txt_Idt').val();
    //alert("check what" + txtVal);
    if (isDate(txtVal)) {
        $(".basicForm").validate().element(".txt_Idt");
        $(".basicForm").find(".txt_Idt").removeClass("errRed");
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    } else {
        alert('Kindly enter date in valid format');
        $("#txt_Idt").addClass("errRed");
        $(".txt_Idt").val("");
        $(".basicForm").validate().element(".txt_Idt");
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    return false;
});

function isDate(txt_Idt) {
    var currVal = txt_Idt;
    if (currVal == '') return false;

    var rxDatePattern = /^\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4}$/; //Declare Regex
    var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

    if (dtArray == null) return false;

    //Checks for mm/dd/yyyy format.
    dtMonth = dtArray[3];
    dtDay = dtArray[5];
    dtYear = dtArray[1];

    if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12) return false;
    else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31) return false;
    else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31) return false;
    else if (dtMonth == 2) {
        var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
        if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried something like this

```
$(".basicForm").find(".txt_Idt").removeClass("errRed");
```

but still no use

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you have `ID` why are you searching element? You can directly do `$("#txt_Idt").removeClass("errRed")`

Comment: But still not happening initially i did in the way but it was not happening

Comment: Could it be that your hand-rolled date validation routine is imperfect and not returning the boolean value you expect? Perhaps using a library like moment.js which is designed for exactly this kind of thing would yield better results?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle where we can actually test it?

Comment: Look in your javascript console. `$(...).validate is not a function` - this is preventing the class removal

Comment: fiddle added in the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Change Event

> Depending on the kind of form element being changed and the way the user interacts with the element, the change event fires

#### Issue

When you select date from calendar, element interacted is datepicker and not textbox. So change of datepicker (onSelect) is fired and not change event of textbox.

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ean5be0x/).

#### Code

```js
$("#txtTest").on("change", function() {
  console.log("changed");
});

$("#btnTest").on("click", function() {
  $("#txtTest").val("Button Clicked");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtTest">
<button id="btnTest">Update Text</button>
```

#### Solution

To handle this event, we have to trigger our change event on `onSelect` event of datepicker

```
$("#txt_Idt").trigger("change");
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/akwb5r3L/13/).

#### Reference

[Change Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Comment: what was the issue buddy

Comment: When you select date from date picker, change event is not fired. So you handler was not called and hence no changes in UI state

Comment: I have few minor changes to `change` function. Some better practices [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/akwb5r3L/14/). Also just a case: try typing "31/02/2015". This will pass regex but is not a valid date. I had same issue and had posted it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109765/javascript-date-validation) for better option. Do check this as well.

Comment: Yes. Dont use date picker, just type it. When you use input as datepicker, you have to check these cases. People can use any format, any value. Validating date using Date object is best option

Comment: I have one more query is that possible can i give two text field which having the same same date functionalities

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95041/discussion-between-rajesh-and-mahadevan).

Comment: @Mahadevan have updated my answer with proper explanation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you remove the following statement from the code(2 times exists):

```
$(".basicForm").validate().element(".txt_Idt");
```

Comment: if user enter some radnom numb and click outisde an error message will come and alert will come 
second if user enter the correct date error class will remove then the error message should update

Comment: validate() is causing the console error which makes the code not works.

Comment: but the problem is if i am not putting this validate function it was not updating even if i enter wrong value

Comment: Validate functions error you have to handle it. We can fix the errors in the code which you provided.

Answer (score 0):

when you find elements for a class you will need to interact beetween elements.

Look at this function:

```
function serializeForm(idForm, submitHidden) {

// Clona o form para remover as mascaras e submeter.
var formSubmit = $('#' + idForm).clone();

// Todos os campos do form Original
var campos = $('#' + idForm).find(':input');

// Todos os campos do form clonado
var camposSubmit = formSubmit.find(':input');

// Seleciona os campos que estão em divs ocultas.
var camposDesabilitados = $('#' + idForm).find("div:hidden").find(":input");

// Campos alterados dinamicamente (ajax) precisam ser copiados
// (o clone copia o valor original renderizado no HTML).
for (var i = 0; i < campos.length; i++) {

    camposSubmit[i].value = campos[i].value;

    // se os campos hidden não devem ser submetidos
    if (submitHidden) {
        $(camposSubmit[i]).attr("disabled", false);
    }
    else {

        // Bloqueia os campos que estão em divs ocultas.
        if (camposDesabilitados.filter($(campos[i])).length != 0) {

            // se os campos hidden não devem ser submetidos
            $(camposSubmit[i]).attr("disabled", true);
        }
        else {

            $(camposSubmit[i]).attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }
}

// Remove as mascaras de moeda e percentual (mascaras de data, cpf, cnpj e
// cep sao submetidas e removidas server-side);
formSubmit.find(':input[type="text"]').filter('.money, .percentage').each(
        function() {
            $(this).val($(this).maskMoney('unmasked')[0]);
        });

return formSubmit.serialize();
```

}

As you can see this function interacts everytime we use .find()